# Two Columns Sort MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show names in my database based on if the gender is a boy. I'm currently trying this query but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT
  Name,
  COUNT(Name),
  Gender='Boy' AS totalNumber
FROM
  finaldb
GROUP BY
  Name,
  Gender
ORDER BY
  COUNT(Name) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Gender='Boy'` should be in a WHERE clause, not the SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Gender='Boy'` is in the wrong place, put it after WHERE

`SELECT
  Name,
  Gender,
  COUNT(Name) AS totalNumber
FROM
  finaldb
WHERE
Gender='Boy'
GROUP BY
  Name,
  Gender
ORDER BY
  COUNT(Name) DESC
LIMIT 5`

A good place to read up on WHERE and SQL in general:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: where would I make a where case?

Comment: Thanks. What if you want to base it off something else? Like Month and Day and those are two seperate IDs. Showing what appears most often in those two sets of data.

Comment: You can use AND or OR in your WHERE clause to further filter. Example WHERE firstName = 'John' AND lastName = 'Smith', you can do the same with dates etc... I updated my answer with a link.